# How to read *.war manifest file in GWT

Tags: maven, gwt

I have a **.war** file built by Maven, using **gwt-maven-plugin** and **maven-war-plugin**. In **.war** manifest **META-INF/MANIFEST.MF** I have entries describing the artifact ids of web application of its dependencies. I want to read these entries to show them to user in HTML. How can I read manifest file in GWT? In desktop App it is simple:

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF")
```

or

```
this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF")
```

but I cannot do that in GWT because *method is not present in JRE Emulation Library*.

I also tried to use **RequestBuilder**:

```
new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, "META-INF/MANIFEST.MF")
       .sendRequest("", new RequestCallback() {
             @Override
             public void onResponseReceived(Request req, Response resp) {
                 String text = resp.getText();
             }

             @Override
             public void onError(Request res, Throwable throwable) {
                 result.put("Err","Err");
              }
         });
```

but it also does not work (*error 404 - not found*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing in either META-INF or WEB-INF can be read by the user's web browser - that would make it far too easy to download internals of how the war works and either find secrets (config files holding passwords or other details) or gain access to the source and reverse engineer it.

To achieve something like this, you'll need to write a servlet which offers the contents of that file. This probably would start with either of the two sample lines in your project.

This isn't really a GWT question - a GWT app is compiled to JS, not a jar or a war, it just happens to be held within a .war archive in your case.